# Sort JSON String object according to my requirement

Tags: java, json

I am having one list. And I am converting this list to a `JSON` `String` object and send it to UI.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonString = gson.toJson(environmentnamesList);
return jsonString;
```

This is my `JSON` object.

```
[{"id":3272,"company_name":"HCL - Demo"},{"id":3255,"company_name":"IBM1 - Test"},{"id"
:3257,"company_name":"ECO1 - Development"},{"id":3253,"company_name":"MindSpace - Development"
},{"id":3256,"company_name":"ABC - Demo"},{"id":3258,"company_name":"CDF - Test"},
{"id":3205,"company_name":"FGR - Production"},{"id":3208,"company_name":"RFGGDDF - Production"
}]
```

Now i want to sort this `JSON` object by the following criteria:

1. If `company_name` contains `Production(RFGGDDF - Production)` give first priority for that
2. If `company_name` contains `Development(MindSpace - Development)` give second priority
3. If `company_name` contains `Demo (ABC - Demo)` give 3rd priority
4. Id `company_name` contains `Test(IBM1 - Test)` give 4th priority

I want output to look like this:

```
[{"id":3205,"company_name":"FGR - Production"},{"id":3208,"company_name":"RFGGDDF - Production"},
{"id":3257,"company_name":"ECO1 - Development"},{"id":3253,"company_name":"MindSpace - Development"},
{"id":3272,"company_name":"HCL - Demo"},{"id":3256,"company_name":"ABC - Demo"}
,{"id":3258,"company_name":"CDF - Test"},{"id":3255,"company_name":"IBM1 - Test"}]...
```

I tried like this:

```
List<String> envTypes = Arrays.asList("Production", "Development", "Demo", "Test");

         Ordering<Environment> ordering = Ordering.natural().onResultOf(----i don't know what arg i have to pass----);
         Collections.sort(environmentnamesList, ordering);
```

Comment: Umm I would say. Write your own method.

Comment: just now i updated my question can you please take a lookj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest sorting at list level instead of json level.

Something like below. I am assuming you have a java `List` named environmentnamesList which contains   elements of type MyObject .
You can sort the list in below way:-

```
Collections.sort(environmentnamesList, new CustomComparator());
String jsonString = gson.toJson(environmentnamesList);
```

And you can use CustomComparator like given below:-

```
 public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<MyObject> {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
        String[] env =new String[]{"Demo","Test","Developement","Production"};
        int env1=-1,env2=-1;
        for(int i =0; i < env.length; i++)
        {
            if(env1<0 && o1.getCompanyName().contains(env[i]))
            {
                env1=i;
            }

            if(env2<0 && o2.getCompanyName().contains(env[i]))
            {
                env2=i;
            }
        }
        return (env1 < env2) ? 1 :(env1 == env2)? 0: -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: i getting error at new[i]... if(env1<0 && o1.getCompanyName().contains(new[i]))

Comment: @mvswetha corrected it and update the answer.. it shud be env[i] instead of new[i]

Comment: Thank q soooooooo much yar.my prm is sloved.i l used env.... if(env1<0 && o1.getCompanyName().contains(env[i]))

Comment: @mvswetha  you can upvote by clicking on triangle above '2'.. it will turn orange and count will increase if you vote is done..